# Is a question only about the health effects of cookware on topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

[This question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/4562/is-titanium-cookware-safe) from 2013 was recently brought forward. Its only purpose is to find out if using a certain type of cookware, in this case titanium, is safe for the body. It's seeking academic, peer-reviewed, articles, not just opinion.

It was highly voted and has two informative and also highly-voted answers. One mentioned that titanium isn't generally used in backpacking, but mostly they answered the question as posed. There was also a discussion in comments regarding the safety of this cookware, but not seeming to relate it to outdoor activities.

To me, this looks off-topic. I briefly checked the other questions tagged [cooking](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) and this seems to be the only one that asks this type of question without any mention of outdoor activity.

I was thinking of initiating a close vote as off-topic, especially since it's now on the front page and may encourage similar questions. The OP hasn't been seen here for three years, or on the entire SE network for one, so I can't ask for clarification or an edit to tie it to outdoor activities. The authors of the two top answers are still around the network, so they may not appreciate the question being closed.

I did see [this meta discussion](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/448/should-we-get-a-closing-reason-for-questions-that-ask-for-medical-advice), also from 2013, asking if we should create a close reason for questions seeking medical advice. The answer to that was no, which I understand in the context of health problems arising from outdoor activities, but the one which I'm referencing doesn't appear to fall into that category.

My intention is not to go around closing questions for no reason, but I would appreciate clarification regarding this issue, and, in particular, the specific question.

Would someone kindly clarify this for me?

Comment: Since its in TGO and by context id say it seems clear its camping cookware, couldnt the title be edited from "titanium cookware" to "titanium *camping* cookware"?. "*One mentioned that titanium isn't generally used in backpacking*" that one answer says "*Titanium is not commonly found in cookware other than backpacking*" meaning that titanium is usually backpacking stuff not the cookware you would normally use in your kitchen, not the other way around. There has been also a question about safety of mylar pouches+boiling water, they all seem a good fit

Comment: Very good point, and great suggestion.  As I said to ab2, I'd be happy to go ahead and do the edit as long as it doesn't feel like plagiarizing to you!

Comment: its not a problem for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch on this question!  I suggest editing the question so the first sentence reads something like:

Titanium cookware is attractive for backpacking because of its lightness.

This jibes with one of the answers, and maybe is what prompted the question in the first place.

In general, I don't like closing old questions (which can lead to deletion) because I think the evolutionary record of the site might be of interest someday.

Comment: Excellent points by you and @Erik vanDoren. I had thought about editing but hadn't come up with something suitable. I'm more than happy to do the edit but feel like I'm plagiarizing both of you! If you think it would be helpful, I'll go ahead and do it.

Comment: @Sue Fine by me if you do the edit.

Comment: Done! Feel free to change if I didn't get it right. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 4):

This question got so many upvotes exactly because it asked about titanium cookware.  As a hiker it never occurred to me that it would be off topic.  Titanium cookware is used almost exclusively for backpacking where the weight reduction is (for some) worth the markup.  Similarly questions about GoPros would be (without a clear reason otherwise) considered on topic because it is gear that is specifically designed for and primarily used in, the outdoors.  Such gear doesn't need any further reason to be considered an outdoors topic.